# Remove white space between dollar sign and custom field "price"

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using custom fields to display prices (except for the dollar sign). My goal is to code the dollar sign within the theme, but I encountered an issue.

The reason I am using this approach is because if I enter a dollar sign in the custom field I will not be able to use `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`
And I need to use a conditional statement to display the dollar sign because not all posts will have prices.

The code below results in

$ 9.75

Notice the white space between the dollar sign and the number "9". How can I remove the white space? Or is there an alternative method to code a dollar sign using a conditional statement ?

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true) ) { ?>
$
<?php } ?>

<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed the whitespaces in the code itself and optimized it a bit (didn't understand why would you have a condition for the dollar sign, but not for the price itself), this should work:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true) ) {
   echo '$', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true);
} ?>
```

---

Where was space coming from in the original code:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true) ) { ?>
$<!- HERE ->
<?php } ?>   <!- HERE ->
<!- AND HERE ->
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true); ?>
```

See the idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/93mcu7sj/

Comment: THANK YOU Shmoz! This is so much simpler! Needless to say I am a Noob and had no idea what I was doing. Lol

Comment: Haha, you're welcome, I hope I helped you understand it a bit better.